# Windows 7 GitHub hangs while loading changes from large repository

Tags: github

I am running GitHub gui on Windows 7, added a repository with an existing site (about 600mb) and when I click on 'open repository' I see 'loading changes' with the loader but after about 2 min the loader stops and the program hangs until the point windows asks if I would like to restart or close the program.

Anyone else experienced this and found a solution?

Comment: Sorry, I think this is not directly programming-related, therefore SO might really be the wrong place to ask :-(

Comment: Thanks. I don't think Git has a forum do they? Maybe I will email support@github.com

Comment: I think mailing them might be the right solution, I got a minor problem a few months back and the responded very quickly and solved it for me. At least they will tell you where to ask if they can't solve it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I've seen this before after a developer accidentally checked in a SQL dump into the repo.  GitHub for Windows doesn't do well with large repositories.  Instead, fire up GitGUI and do the clone yourself with `git clone REPOSITORY_URL`.  (As a bonus, you'll get a progress bar).